# How to clear textbox using jquery(with ConfirmButtonExtender)?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have mentioned my code below, the problem is I am unable to clear `textbox`. Kindly see my javascript code for  textbox clearing and piont out the error?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function CancelClick() {
     document.getElementById("<%=txtname.ClientID %>").innerHTML =txtname.Text='';
 }
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
<div>
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel2" runat="server">   
</asp:UpdatePanel>     
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm" onclick="btnConfirm_Click" />
<asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" TargetControlID    ="btnConfirm" 
ConfirmText ="Are you sure you want to click this?" OnClientCancel ="CancelClick" 
ConfirmOnFormSubmit="false"  runat="server">
</asp:ConfirmButtonExtender>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `value` not the `innerHtml`:

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtname.ClientID %>").value = '';
```

Comment: In place of button click shall we perform this with dropdownlist?

Comment: @BrunoBlane That's up to you to decide though it makes more sense to be triggered on a button click, to me at least.

Comment: why asked first I applied this with dropdown but it shows dropdownlist not support this action

Comment: I have another doubt, I am new in stack overflow so let me know how to write words in block quotes(U have did Value in block quote in your answer)

Comment: For that you use single quote characters. Click the `help` button when adding a comment to see the markdown syntax available to you.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery (as you asked for)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function CancelClick() {
     $("#<%=txtname.ClientID %>").val("");
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it shouldn't be just $("#txtname").val("");?
I'm not programming in ASP Forms (only in MVC), but it looks more logical. Look at his textbox

Comment: @PawełReszka No, he needs to get the `ClientID` of the control or else the selector wont match.

Comment: It could be both. Id names in webforms can be crappy, so to be sure you have the correct id, its normal to use .ClientID.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought that txtname was DOM Id. Man, I don't like webforms just by looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function CancelClick() {
     var textBoxId = '<%= #txtname.ClientID %>';
     $(textBoxId).val('');
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Yea, thanks for review. My bad there. But that isn't a - motive, it was just a typo.